# perform 2 way sync between online and offline databases

Tags: sql, database, mobile, synchronization, offline

I'm building a webapp that has a mobile app companion.  The mobile app can be used in offline mode.

What is the best way to keep the central database and the local database on the client apps in sync?

In this case, changes could be happening in the webapp and also on the local app in offline mode.  How do I make sure that when a network connection is available, that both databases are in sync.

Keep in mind that the local app would only have a subset of the data.  Ie.. only data pertinent to that user.

This seems like a common use case for apps.  Is there an available framework for this?

Thank you.

Comment: what platform are you using? iOS, Android etc. ?

Comment: So, two native apps or one mobile web app?

Comment: a mobile app for both ios and android.. all syncing with a webapp.